# How to reverse the order of a SETOF in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

I have a complex PSQL function returning `SETOF` of a table record (ancestry path of a leaf record in a tree, yikes), usually only a couple of records at a time - the ancestors - and this fits into the rest of the application perfectly.

For example, given records:

```
id: 5, parent_id: null
id: 1, parent_id: 5
id: 3, parent_id: 1
```

should the function be called as `get_ancestry(3)` I expect it to return `SETOF` records containing `3, 1, 5` in this exact order - and order is important obviously.

However, there is this *one tiny little important place* where I need to iterate over the records of that `SETOF` in the exact reverse order, in the example before, the expected result would be `5, 1, 3`.

Or in other words *given a function that returns SETOF, how to write a function that returns that same SETOF in reverse order?*

- there's no `ORDER BY` I can use to help myself along - I could easily compute it virtually, but how to add it to the record object belonging to a table?
- I thought of converting the `SETOF` into an array and then reversing the array, but found nothing googling - not about reversing the array, nor about converting the `SETOF` into an array
- I thought of adding a `level` attribute which would be equal to 0 if the record is top-level, that records' children would have `level=1` etc, but adding another column to a super-busy ever-updating table for this one query which *must* work somehow better seems just wrong
- rewriting the complex function to do it's quite tricky logic in the exact same way but recursing a different path seems like a maintenance/bugfix nightmare

What to do?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name done as requested!

Comment: To be honest, the whole question is in the title and it seems quite clear. "given a function that returns SETOF, how to write a function that returns that same SETOF in reverse order".

Answer (score 1):

> *I thought of adding a level attribute*

You don't have to add that to the table, you can calculate that dynamically in your query.

Something like this:

```
with recursive tree (id, parent_id, level) as (
  select id, parent_id, 1 as level
  from the_table
  where parent_id is null
  union all
  select c.id, c.parent_id, p.level + 1
  from the_table c
    join data p on p.id = c.parent_id
)
select *
from tree;
```

If you want to walk the tree from a leaf to the parent, you need to change the recursive query:

```
with recursive tree (id, parent_id, level) as (
  select id, parent_id, 1 as level
  from the_table
  where id = 42
  union all
  select x.id, x.parent_id, p.level + 1
  from the_table x
    join data p on x.id = p.parent_id
)
select *
from tree;
```

Note that in that case the "meaning" of the level columns is reversed. It essentially defines the distance of each row from the starting point. It is not the overall level in the complete hierarchy.

The above can be put into a function:

```
create function get_tree(p_start_with integer) 
   returns table(id integer, parent_id integer, level integer)
as
$$
  ... the query from above using the p_start_with parameter
$$
language sql;
```

Then you can use

```
select *
from get_tree(42)
order by level desc;
```

You should also add another column that would define the order of children on the same level if that is important for you. Or just use something like `order by level desc, id desc` to get a consistent order for all elements on the same level.

Comment: Hmm, a recursive `with` query, thank you, I'll play with it :)

Comment: Ah yes, the problem is, the function needs to start not from any top (`parent_id is null`) but from a specific leaf and then traverse to the top (because each parent has many children). But you give me a good idea <3

Comment: @bbozo: that is not a problem. You need to change the condition in the non-recursive part and also the join in the recursive part.

Answer (score 1):

To reverse the returned order, you can do a sub-query and order by original row number. It is important to underline that row_number() over() is using rows "as they come" so your get_ancestry() function must control this order, else you risk inconsistent results.

```
select * from 
 (select  a.*, 
          row_number() over() as sortID
 from get_ancestry(3) a) b
order by sortID desc;
```

Comment: Interrresting, yes `get_ancestry` returns "rows as they come", this should work